# Возможно ли проверить три строки между собой методом compare?

Tags: c#, строки

Нужно проверить три вводимые строки методом compare и вывести две наименьшие.
Как это реализовать и возможно ли вообще? Compare ведь сравнивает только две строки или нет?

Comment: Так же, как с тремя числами - в два этапа -  сравнить две строки, потом третью сравнить с большей.

Comment: сначала сравнить первую со второй, потом вторую с третьей потом третью с первой

Answer (score 0):

Мое предложение:

1. занести все 3 строки в array а потом сортировать его.
2. При чем здесь compare? При том, что сортировка его использует внутри себя. :D
3. А раз у нас есть аррей отсортированый, то мы можем просто вывести две первые или две последние строки нашего аррея на консоль. В зависимости от того, как мы отсортировали -- по возрастанию или по убыванию...

PS: преподаватель может как принять такой ответ как слишком хитрожопый, так и не принять по той же причине.

Ну а иначе... как и писали в коментах к самому вопросу)